# Why won't my install on Macbook work?

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, live-usb, macbook

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Macbook. The CD drive is broken, so I am going from a USB flash drive I created.  I can get it to "Try Ubuntu" perfectly fine, as a matter of fact I'm using it right now.

However, I really want to install. Everything is partitioned, rEFIt is installed.  I run the installer and I follow the guide at [Apple Intel Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) I get to the install part of the installer, and after running it ends with a fatal grub error.

Anyone know how to get past this?  I feel like it has something to do with the fact that I don't get the last dialog box of the installer with the "advanced" tab used in the guide. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've had the same problem on my desktop.
My problem whas an SSD (OCZ revodrive). I am not sure what SSD you have but I think its the SSD's fault.

Answer (score 1):

I had a really hard time getting a working install of Linux on my Macbook Pro 6.2 with a few versions not even getting to the "Try Ubuntu", others creeping a little further.

In the end, I managed to get a copy of [Xubuntu 12.10](http://mirror.iawnet.sandia.gov/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.10/alpha-3/) to run. But even while partitioning, I experienced errors. I had to avoid making a home partition and let the installer proceed then retro create a home partition.

For the partitioning and EFI boot this source was very useful:
[EUFI Booting Ubuntu on a Mac.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html)

For the sorting out my home partition this helped: [How to create a separate home partition after installing Ubuntu.](http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/)